# How to add plugins to cordova/phonegap app without using command npm?

Tags: node.js, plugins, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm wondering if there is any convenient way to add plugins to hybrid app without using npm. For example I've created a phonegap app using their program so I did't have to use npm commands. But now I want to add this plugin to my app "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" and I can't because constantly pop up different errors. I've searched for the solutions in internet but the reasons are different (always something in my windows is missing). So I've decided to reinstall windows and install everything afresh. But I thought that is a good question anyway. So is there any other way to do it? And If some one would be so kind and do for me a sample corova app with already added crosswalk plugin I would be happy because I will reinstall my windows next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is any other convenient way. And respecting your problem just add this code:

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" version="1.3.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt" source="npm" version="1.4.0-dev-11"/>
```

to your config.xml